# Publishing::: ClickOnce or Windows Installer

Tags: vb.net

While publishing, how can I select ClickOnce or Windows Installer.  Where can the choice be made?
Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup clickonce deployment in your applications properties page. Right click your project in solution explorer and select properties. For windows installer you need to create a new windows setup project.

Both are pretty easy:

**clickonce:**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228283(VS.80).aspx

**Setup and deployment project:**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3bb4tfd%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an MSI, I would recommend using WiX.

The downside to the VS Deployment Projects is that they require Visual Studio to build (which should be unnecessary on a CI build server).

WiX has a bit more of a learning curve (and the odd gotcha too), but is much easier in the long run. Lots of online resources, including the [WiX category here at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wix).